# List of objects that are still referenced after gc()

Tags: java, garbage-collection, destructor

Just like in RStudio or Python IDEs, where it is displyed a list of objets that are instantiated, what are the options to reproduce this in Java?

After [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567935/how-to-delete-an-array-properly-in-java) in which the comunity explained how to delete a two dimentional array, other questions have arise. Also, altough I trust the users who answered the question, how can I prove/see with my own eyes that the array/object indeed gets deleted after calling `cg()`?

Comment: @Shloim as the post was pointed as duplicate and indeed answer my question, the correct option would be deleting my post or leaving it as it is?

Comment: click “That solved my problem!”, and the Community user will instantly close it.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled